# Iterating through each array in array of arrays

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have an array of arrays:

```
array = [
          [1,2,3],
          [4,5,6],
          [7,8,9]
        ]
```

How would I iterate over each array and print them out individually, without using `map`?

Something like

```
array.each do |a|  
  puts a
end

> [1,2,3]
> [4,5,6]
> [7,8,9]
```

Comment: Replace `puts a` with another `.each` call, this time with `a.each` instead of `array.each`.

Answer (score 3):

The `to_s` method of Array gives a string representation.

```
array = [ [1,2,3],
          [4,5,6],
          [7,8,9]]

array.each do |a|  
  puts a.to_s  #or just: p a
end
```

Output

```
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6]
[7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: I initially missed your comment, `#or just: p a`. That would seem to be the better (and more conventional) way, as it does not require the creation of a new object.

Comment: @CarySwoveland `p` just calls `inspect`. AFAIK it creates a new String.